# how to convert list to str. 'DataFrame' object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe

Please let me know how to convert list to str.

My dataframe(df_meta_review1) structure sample:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
userID    categories                    category_domain(I want a this!)
-----------------------------------------------------
a1010     [pc, game]                    pc,game-A
a1011     [mobile, game, education]     mobile, game, education-A
```

I already tried belows

```
1. df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = df_meta_review1['categories'].astype('str')    #error!

2. df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = df_meta_review1(['categories']).apply(','.join)  #error!

3. df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = ",".join(map(str, df_meta_review1(['categories'])))   #error!
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated your table with the following code

```py
df_meta_review1 = pd.DataFrame([('a101',['pc', 'game']),('a1001', ['mobile', 'game', 'education'])], columns = ['userID', 'categories'])
```

Running the first piece of code gives no error. Are you sure you get an error when its run? Below is the resultant table.

```py
  userID                 categories                  category_domain
0   a101                 [pc, game]                   ['pc', 'game']
1  a1001  [mobile, game, education]  ['mobile', 'game', 'education']
```

If I run the second line, I also get an error. Like so:

```py
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

To fix this I remove the round parenthesis from after the data frame name, as the error suggests you we are trying to use the data frame as a function (this is what callable means)

```py
df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = df_meta_review1['categories'].apply(','.join)
```

This no longer generates an error and the output looks like:

```py
  userID                 categories        category_domain
0   a101                 [pc, game]                pc,game
1  a1001  [mobile, game, education]  mobile,game,education
```

Which, I think is what you are looking for.
For the third line of code I get the error:

```py
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Again, dropping the round parenthesis from after the data frame name, yields code that executes without error.

```py
df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = ",".join(map(str, df_meta_review1['categories']))
```

However I don't think it is what you are looking for.

```py
  userID                 categories                                 category_domain
0   a101                 [pc, game]  ['pc', 'game'],['mobile', 'game', 'education']
1  a1001  [mobile, game, education]  ['pc', 'game'],['mobile', 'game', 'education']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `apply` function that loop through the dataframe and define a function to return the results for each row, like this:

```
def app(row):
    return ",".join(row['categories'])
```

and pass this to apply function:

```
df_meta_review1['category_domain'] = df_meta_review1.apply(lambda x: app(x),axis =1)
```

output:

```
  userID                 categories          category_domain
0   a101                 [pc, game]                  pc,game
1  a1001  [mobile, game, education]    mobile,game,education
```